# The convertion of an excel file to a dat file is incomplete

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I convert an excel file to dat with python, the dat file doesnt have all the rows of the excel file. The convertion i incomplete:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_excel('Y:\.......\File.xlsm', sheet_name=2,header=None)
a = a.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
b=open('Y:\.......\File.dat','w+')
c=a.to_string(b,index=False,header=None)
```

Comment: Is there only 1 row missing?

Comment: no, many rows. For example I have 30 rows, only 20 rows that are present in the dat file.

Comment: Does the DF has all the rows ?

Comment: It's ok it works now I did this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_excel('Y:\.......\File.xlsm', sheet_name=2,header=None)
a = a.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
c=a.to_string(open('Y:\.......\File.dat','w+'),index=False,header=None)